# Changing button value with fade? Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, button, jquery-animate

I'm changing the value of my button like this

```
$('#slideButton').val("Expand");
```

and back like this

```
$('#slideButton').val("Collapse");
```

If possible, how can I have just the button's value fade out/in, but not fade the entire button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### HTML

Use `button` instead of `input`.

```
<button id="slideButton" type="button"><span>Expand</span></button>​
```

### JQuery

```
$('#slideButton').click(function()
{
    $(this).find('span').html('Collapse').hide().fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sKcE3/